# How do I generate .LU file from .JSON file of LUIS

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line-interface, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am working on Bot framework Virtual Assistant Template. There is a deployment folder where .LU files resides. But i created  LUIS app in LUIS site and can export LUIS app as JSON format.  Currently i am generating .lu file manually. **Is there any option that i can generate .lu file using command lines or cli or some thing with help of JSON file that i exported.**

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to `LUDown` tool in BotBuilder tools, and in particular to its `refresh` method:

- LUDown github is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Ludown)
- Refresh is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/Ludown/docs/refresh-command.md):

> You can use the refresh command to re-generate .lu files from your
>   LUIS JSON and / or QnAMaker JSON files.

Answer (score -3):

Below is command line to generate .lu from json file

Note: We have to change directory to npm.

C:\Users\local\AppData\Roaming\npm>ludown refresh -i "

Comment: ok, what is the purpose of posting an answer taking exactly the command provided in the other answer? Moreover, answering with just a command line may not be a good practice for people who will need more information about that command (where does it comes from, what are the parameters, etc)